# Adding text to each page of PDF with itext instead of just the first page

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to add text to each page of a PDF using this code which works great, but this code is only for adding text to the first page:

```
            //variables
        String pathin = @"C:\Users\root\Desktop\temp\test.pdf";
        String pathout = @"C:\Users\root\Desktop\temp\test2.pdf";

//create a document object
//var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
//create PdfReader object to read from the existing document
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pathin);

//create PdfStamper object to write to get the pages from reader 
PdfStamper stamper=new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(pathout, FileMode.Create));
// PdfContentByte from stamper to add content to the pages over the original content
PdfContentByte pbover = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
//add content to the page using ColumnText
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pbover, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("Hello World"), 10, 10, 0);
// PdfContentByte from stamper to add content to the pages under the original content
//PdfContentByte pbunder = stamper.GetUnderContent(1);

//close the stamper
stamper.Close();
```

I've seen examples using:

```
   for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        document.NewPage();

                        var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                        var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
```

To iterate through each page, but I'm having trouble tying that into my code above.  Any helps would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your first snippet, you hardcode the page number:

```
 stamper.GetUnderContent(1);
```

In your second snippet, you loop over the pages:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)  {
}
```

Now combine these two snippets:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)  {
       PdfContentByte pbunder = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
       // do stuff with bunder
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, that worked perfectly!  I really really love itext, thanks for contributing in so many ways, and thanks for the free book!